# Skip reverse path in neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an example graph of 5 nodes connected via 4 edges.
[image]

```
    create (a:Person {name:'A'}), (b:Person {name:'B'}),  (c:Person {name:'C'}), (d:Person {name:'D'}), (e:Person {name:'E'}), (b)-[:KNOWS]->(a), (b)-[:KNOWS]->(c), (d)-[:KNOWS]->(c), (d)-[:KNOWS]->(e)
```

And I would like to select all the node triplets barring duplicates.

```
MATCH (p)--(q)--(r) RETURN DISTINCT p,q,r
```

[Here is the playground](https://console.neo4j.org/r/9b4m6t)

What I want as a result is only 3 triplets

```
a-b-c
b-c-d
c-d-e
```

but what I get instead is also the reversed triplets

```
a-b-c
b-c-d
c-d-a
c-b-a
d-c-b
e-d-c
```

How can I avoid selecting reverse path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:

WHERE id(p) < id(r)